# concat two lists in a list of lists

Tags: python

Is it possible to concat two lists in a list of lists?
From:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listB = ['A', 'B', 'C']
listFull = listA + listB
```

To:

```
print(listFull)
[['a', 'A'],['b', 'B'],['c', 'C']]
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried writing any code yourself?

Comment: I mean in a simple way, without using a for inside another for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

List comprehension using `zip()`

```py
listFull = [list(x) for x in zip(listA, listB)]
print(listFull)
```

You can also use `map()` without looping

```py
listFull = list(map(list, zip(listA, listB)))
```

---

```
[['a', 'A'],['b', 'B'],['c', 'C']]
```

Answer (score -1):

there are several ways to achieve this.
you either need atleast 1 for loop or a map/zip combination.
both possibilities here:

```
listA = ['a', 'b', 'c']
listB = ['A', 'B', 'C']
#1
listFull =[]
for i in range(len(listA)):
    listFull.append([listA[i],listB[i]])
print(listFull)
# output [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']]

#2
listfull2 = list(map(list,zip(listA,listB)))
print(listfull2)
# output [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C']]
```

Answer (score -2):

"Concatenate" is what the `+` does, which puts one list after another. What you're describing is called a "zip" operation, and Python has [exactly that function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in.

`zip` returns an iterable, so if you want a list, you can call `list` on it.

```
print(list(zip(listA, listB)))
# Output: [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]
```

Comment: But I want ```[['a', 'A'],['b', 'B'],['c', 'C']]```